# DataTables get values of all inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So now i have an issue with serialize all inputs of my DataTable. I try to get all values of every pagination table, and then send to server via AJAX, but before that i debug my code with console and serialized date looks like this:

> cart%5BGA117110020001%5D=0&cart%5BCA117210020001%5D=0&cart%5BZA117210020001%5D=0&cart%5BCA117310020001%5D=0&cart%5BZA117310020001%5D=0&cart%5BZA117310030001%5D=0&cart%5BZC117410020001%5D=0&cart%5BZB117410020001%5D=0&cart%5BZA117510020001%5D=0&cart%5BZA117610020001%5D=0&cart%5BZA117010020001%5D=0&cart%5BOX103812000001%5D=0&cart%5BZC103812000001%5D=0&cart%5BZA103812000001%5D=0&cart%5BZB103812000001%5D=0&cart%5BOX103815000001%5D=0&cart%5BZC103815000001%5D=0&cart%5BZA103815000001%5D=0&cart%5BZB103815000001%5D=0&cart%5BOX103808500001%5D=0&cart%5BZC103808500001%5D=0&cart%5BZA103808500001%5D=0&cart%5BZB103808500001%5D=0&cart%5BZA103712000001%5D=0&cart%5BZB103712000001%5D=0&cart%5BZA103715000001%5D=0&cart%5BZB103715000001%5D=0&cart%5BZA103708500001%5D=0& ...

I dont know why, but to every row i get '%5B'product.code'%5D', how to prepare an array or JSON object with values of input in every row ?

Here's my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#datatable-default').DataTable();
$('#getData').click( function () {

    var paginator = $('#datatable-default').DataTable();

    var dat = paginator.$('input').serialize();
    console.log(dat);

    alert("stop");
});
});
```

my input looks like:

```
<input type="number" class="spinner-input form-control" min="0" value="0" name="cart[{{ product.code }}]" />
```

Comment: That's just url encoding the string, the server you send it to will be able to understand it just fine

Comment: Paste your output into the box on this site https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and click "decode". That's what your backend will see

Comment: If you're actually have trouble sending the data to the server or reading it there, please post the code you're using to do that and we can take a look.

Comment: Ohh... thanks i forgot about formats :/ now i try to send to server and look on the data. Thank you, i spend over one hour on this issue